# How to execute ajax success function with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get into ajax success callback on specific condition. 
i am passing an argument to ajax function and based on the argument match i am trying to execute the function..

i have an if condition where if the parameter is `abc` then url will be something and if parameter is `xyz` then i am trying to jump to success function. but i am unable to do it.. how can i do it, here's what i have tried to do.

```
function Call(type){
    $.ajax({
            if(type != 'xyz'){
                var url = "/param1/api/me?id="+kId+"&clickType="+type;
            }else{
                //jump to success callback
            }           
            success = function(data){
                if(type == "abc"){
                    console.log('abc');
                } else if(type == "asd"){
                    console.log('asd');
                } else if(type == "gst"){
                    console.log('gst');
                } else if(type == "xyz"){
                    console.log('xyz');
                };
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do. Do you want to have a different url according to type and then do something different in the callback? Anyway, your code is not valid javascript

Answer (score 0):

Oh. You mean like this?

```
function Call(type){
    if(type != 'xyz'){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/param1/api/me?id="+kId+"&clickType="+type,
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    }elseif(type == "abc"){
        console.log('abc');
    } else if(type == "asd"){
        console.log('asd');
    } else if(type == "gst"){
        console.log('gst');
    } else if(type == "xyz"){
        console.log('xyz');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d == "-505") {
               // Error page
            }
            else if (data.d == "-501") {
              // other page
            }
            successfunction(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //$.messager.alert('Warning', errormessage);

        }
    });
```